# Problems Sending Attachments in PHP through Google SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

Hey there, I'm unable to recompile PHP on the server I'm working on, so I believe my best option for handling this functionality (our company recently moved to GoogleApps for email) is via some socket based email.   The issue seems to be that when I actually send the mail, the headers and message appear inline, and not as an attachment.  I think this is probably an easy fix and I'm just missing something

I downloaded a great smtp mail class, but it didn't have any functionality for attachments so I had to manually alter the class.  This class was originally written by @author wooptoo, http://wooptoo.com.   In the interest of not putting their work widly out on the internet I'm only going to post the relevant code portions:

```
function attach($attachments){  
$semi_rand = md5(time());  
$this->mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  
$fileatt = $attachments[0]["file"]; // Path to the file    
$fileatt_type = $attachments[0]["content_type"]; // File Type    
$fileatt_name = basename($attachments[0]["file"]); // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment    
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');  
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));  
fclose($file);  
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));  
$email_message = "--{$this->mimeBoundary}\n" .  
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .  
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .  
//"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .  
//" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .  
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .  
    $data . "\n\n" .  
    "--$this->mimeBoundary\n";  
$this->hasAttachment = '1';  
$this->attachmentData = $email_message;  
}
```

The above sets the attachment to the mail object, and the below code sends it

```
function send($from, $to, $subject, $message, $headers=null) {
if($this->hasAttachment == '1')
{
    $headers .=  "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$this->mimeBoundary}\"";
    $message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "--{$this->mimeBoundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type:text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message ."\n\n" . 
    $this->attachmentData;
}
    fputs($this->conn, 'MAIL FROM: <'. $from .'>'. $this->nl);
    fgets($this->conn);
    fputs($this->conn, 'RCPT TO: <'. $to .'>'. $this->nl);
    fgets($this->conn);
    fputs($this->conn, 'DATA'. $this->nl);
    fgets($this->conn);
    fputs($this->conn,
        'From: '. $from .$this->nl.
        'To: '. $to .$this->nl.
        'Subject: '. $subject .$this->nl.
        $headers .$this->nl.
        $this->nl.
        $message . $this->nl.
        '.' .$this->nl
    );

    fgets($this->conn);
    return;
}
```

Comment: http://phpmailer.worxware.com or http://swiftmailer.org  Either will do what you're doing with FAR less hassle, FAR better diagnostics.

Comment: I had been avoiding phpmailer because of the crazy malware warning google popped when I went there.  I'll check those two out though

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested I wrote [a Facade](https://github.com/fterenzani/SwiftMail) for Swiftmailer. Below an example:

```
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport(...);

SwiftMail::setDefaultTransport($transport);

SwiftMail::newInstance($subject, $message)
  ->attachFile($path, $contentType)
  ->setFrom(...)
  ->setTo(...)
  ->send();
```